# Start XAMPP in docker witouth ROOT

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I installed xampp inside a docker using the standard xampp installer and wrote a startup script that I set as the CMD that starts xampp. My problem is that to start xampp root is required. And on heroku where I intend to host this docker, the instances are run without root access. Is there a way to avoid this problem, set the permission differently or create it in a different manner?

Hers is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get -y install iputils-ping && \
  apt-get -y install net-tools && \
  apt-get clean

COPY xampp-linux-x64-8.1.0-0-installer.run /opt/xampp-linux-x64-8.1.0-0-installer.run

RUN chmod +x /opt/xampp-linux-x64-8.1.0-0-installer.run && \
  bash -c ./opt/xampp-linux-x64-8.1.0-0-installer.run && \
  sed -i.bak s'/Require local/Require all granted/g' /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf && \
#  sed -i.bak s'/Listen 80/Listen ${PORT}/g' /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf && \
  sed -i.bak s'/display_errors=Off/display_errors=On/g' /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini && \
  sed -i.bak s'/post_max_size=40M/post_max_size=100M/g' /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

COPY startup.sh /startup.sh

RUN useradd -m xamppuser
USER xamppuser
```

And here is the startup.sh script:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
while :
do  
    sleep 2m
    /opt/lampp/lampp status
done
```

Thanks for helping out

Comment: xampp stands for *Cross-Platform*, Apache, MySQL, PHP, and Perl. With Docker you no longer need the cross-platform part, instead go directly with Apache + PHP if you know Apache already. If you don't know Apache, skip it and go with NGINX or Caddy. Here is a good write up on the latter - https://www.colada.be/caddy-php-and-docker.html. As for DB use something that will persist your docker restarts - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb. This does not answer the question that's why I am leaving this as comment only. Good luck! :)